# Modifying jQuery Autocomplete functionality to match suggestions output

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have the following piece of code.

```
var data=["NYC - New York City", "LA - Los Angeles", "SF - San Francisco"];
$function(){
    $("#title").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response){
            var matcher=new RegExp("^"+$ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term),"i");
            response($grep(data, function(item){
                return matcher.test(item);
            }));
        }
    });
});
```

When I type NYC, I get 'NYC - New York City' in my list of suggestions. Same for LA and SF. However, when I type New York City, I do not get any suggestions. Can anyone please help me with this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression used to match strings is searching from the beginning of the string (`"^"`) – you can remove this to match the typed string anywhere in the data strings:

```
var matcher = new RegExp($ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
```

Also, you can use word boundaries if you want to match from the beginning of a particular word:

```
var matcher = new RegExp("\b" + $ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
```

which for example if "an" were typed, it would match "Angeles" but not "San" or "Francisco".

**Edit:**

Here is a JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/Lrtuyeph/) which shows the really simple example of just passing the `data` array as the `source` property – the default behavior does what you want it to do.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Chris. Changing the regex to use word boundaries was what I was looking for.